# Challenges in Halo 4 not showing up

Tags: halo-4

I used to get challenges in Halo 4, but they simply don't show up anymore. Each day in the Career menu there is a star showing there are new ones, but when I open it to look for descriptions there are no challenges to be done. I'm level 53 and have only completed 12 challenges. Are they not doing them anymore, or is there a bug on my profile?